# Lambda function that instantiates an object

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I'm trying to turn a List to a map, with key being each element of the list and the value being a new ArrayList.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
List<String> strLst = ...
Map<String, List<Foo>> map = strLst.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), _unused -> new ArrayList<>()));
```

Is there a better way than to do: `_unused -> new ArrayList<>()`?

---

To clarify my use case:
I have an API that takes in a list of resource Ids (i.e. this is `List<String> strLst` in example above) and I need to get the list of resources associated with each resource id (it's 1 to many mapping). It needs to return a map where the keyset of the map has all the resource Ids. The value for each resource Id is an empty list if the resource has no mapping. (but I want map.keySet to be equivalent to the original list)

I cannot do

```
for (String resourceId : allResourceIds) {
  List<Result> results = getResults(resourceId);
  map.put (resourceId, results)
}
```

because I need to call a bulk API for performance reasons

```
Map<String, List<Result>> map = ... // this is the step i'm trying to implement
List<Result> allResults = bulkGetResults(allResourceIds)
for (Result res : allResults) {
  map.get(res.getResourceId()).add(res)
}
```

Comment: If the arraylist has a constructor parameter (that makes sense to use) for `_unused` then you could do `ArrayList::new` but outside that not really. Though why a map of elements to an empty list, vs say `Collectors#groupingBy`

Comment: I would look at how this Map is used, most likely you don't need this step.

Comment: added clarification

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you first want to initiate an empty Map with an ArrayList of empty values and afterwards fill it with the result of your bulk call.

Depending on your situation you could combine these steps as follows:

```
Map<String, List<Result>> results = allResults.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Result::getResourceId));
```

If you are only interested in the resources returned by the bulk fetch, that should do it. If you really need an empty list when there is no result, you could solve that later on as a separate concern, e.g.

```
public List<Result> getResult(String resourceId){
    List<Result> resources = results.get(resourceId);
    return resources != null ? resources : Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the first solution is good, but I do need to return empty lists for keys that have no results. The second solution,however, requires wrapping the result in a class instead of returning the map directly.

Comment: If you need that and you don't want to wrap I think there are not a lot of other options left. You could add the empty lists afterwards by streaming over the ids, filter out those with an empty value and foreach missing one add an empty list with Collections::emptyList () but I don't know if thats cleaner or not than your first solution. On my phone so can't code it now I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create your resource map first, then later fill out the missing resourceId:

```
Map<String, List<Result>> resultMap = bulkGetResults(allResourceIds).stream()
                            .collect(groupingBy(Result::getResourceId));

strLst.stream().forEach(id -> resultMap.putIfAbsent(id, new ArrayList<>()));
```